# C# - Rectangle on current mouse point

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I would like to replicate the following cursor:
[image: Cursor]

What I need is to draw that small red square where the pointer is everytime I move the mouse. This is a picturebox control by the way.

What would be the best way to replicate this square?

So, with the help of @CBinet I've been able to do this "pointer square". I've put the code in the Paint event of the picturebox, and in the MouseMove event I store the current point of the mouse and do the picturebox.Invalidate method.

However, now I need to place my cursor created from a file like in the first screenshot, in the bottom of the square. At this moment I have this:

[image: cursor]

As I said, I need to place the cursor in the right bottom corner of the square so it can be like the first screenshot.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: You should provide an attempt (actual code) at trying what you want to achieve and point out where you have a problem.

Comment: Do you want to rectangle to persist or follow the mouse? For the former you may either draw into the image with a graphicsfromImage object in the move event or onto the pbox int the Paint event and its e.graphics parameter. For the latter also use the move event using a pbox.creategraphics object and a refresh call before drawing.

Comment: Are you wanting to add the box to any current cursor or could you just create a cursor file and set the cursor to that new cursor every time you want it?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad Nearly all cursor are already have graphics to top left corner so adding to existing is certain he can't do that. He do need to create new one like you suggest. Probably much easier

Comment: @Mat I didn't have any code, I tried somethings but it didn't work correctly so I came here to ask what would be the best way.

Comment: @TaW yes I do. I've done it in the Paint event of the picturebox.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I would like to have my cursor from a file and the "pointer square" like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx), you can get the position of the cursor on the screen. Then you can draw a rectangle at that position with an arbitrary size then offset the rectangle by minus half of his size.

```
int x = Cursor.Position.X;
int y = Cursor.Position.Y;
int size = 10; // Arbitrary size

System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x - (size / 2), y - (size / 2), size, size);
graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
```

Note that you might have to add a reference to *System.Drawing* in the current project.

More informations : 
[Cursor.Position Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) 
[How to: Draw Graphics on a Windows Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfwzeec0(v=vs.90).aspx)

#### Edit

If you want to position your cursor at the bottom right of the rectangle, all you have to change is the offset of your rectangle :

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x - size, y - size, size, size);
```

Comment: The code you gave helped me achieve what I needed, but now I need help positioning the cursor at the bottom of the square. I've edited my question with this other stuff.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to create you own mouse cursor icon and have the sqaure already part of it like @BlakeThingstad said. Mouse cursor icon cannot be offset. they have fix size

Comment: Ok @Franck, thank you, I guess if that's my only option I'll create the cursor icons.